# Perl CGI download file

Tags: perl, download, cgi

I need to create an HTML file which input text or file. The text will be processed and printed while the file is processed and downloaded.

I am not able to create download. I tried with download header, but it didn't work. A new file will be created with `@array` after processing the file. `output_file.txt` should be downloadable by the user.

```
#!C:/perl64/bin/perl.exe
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI::Pretty qw(:all);


# HTML
print header();
print start_html();
print start_form();
print textfield('text');
print (submit);
print filefield('file');
print submit();
print end_form();
print end_html();

if (param ('file')) {
    my $fh = param('file');
# File processed to get @result and made new file
    open (OUT, ">output/output_file.txt");
    print OUT @result;
# Need to download output_file.txt file
}

# Text processed and printed
elsif(param('text')){
    my $text = param('text')
}
```

Comment: It will throw compile time error.`@result` should be declared as `lexical` before use.

Comment: Each request to your CGI program can return either an HTML page or a file to be downloaded. You can't return both (well, not without using advanced cleverness involving redirects or Javascript).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI::Pretty qw(:all);
my @result;
if (param ('file')) {
    my $file_name=param('file');
    my $file_handle =upload('file');
    my $file_size=-s $file_handle;
    print header(
        -type=>'application/octet-stream',         
        -attachment=> $file_name,
        -Content_Length=>$file_size
    );
# file processed to get @result and made new file 
    binmode($file_handle);
    while (<$file_handle>){
        print $_;
        push (@result,$_);
    }
# need to download output_file.txt file
}
# text processed and printed
elsif(param('text')){
    my $text = param('text');
    print header(
        -type=>'application/octet-stream',         
        -attachment=> "Sample.txt",
        -Content_Length=>length($text)
    );
    print $text;
}

# html 
print header();
print start_html();
print start_form();
print textfield('text');
print (submit);
print end_form();
print start_form();
print filefield('file');
print submit();
print end_form();
print end_html();
```

Comment: Why do you switch between OO and function-based use of CGI.pm? Why do you use the, potentially problematic, `new CGI` syntax instead of the recommended `CGI->new` syntax?

Comment: It's the way I learned to write it. It's the way we use it in other programming languages. Actually we don't need "new CGI" or "CGI->new"

Comment: Yes. But in other languages `new` is a keyword. In Perl it's just a method name. Which is what makes `new Class` rather fragile and best avoided. It's annoying that there is so much documentation out there that uses this syntax. Please don't add to it (and thanks for editing this answer to remove it).

Comment: Thanks man. I wasn't aware of that. It's a great lesson for me. Thanks again for correcting me. I will remember that.

Comment: This script works good but I have some problem in output from upload file: file was processed to @result and made a new file and after that opened and made downloadable file. But, the out file and download file doesn't look same. There are spaces and newline character in downloaded file. Any suggestions? Thanks !

Comment: Can I see the file? Both uploaded and downloaded one?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example I modified:

```
#!C:\Program Files\perl\bin\perl.exe

use CGI ':standard';  
use CGI::Carp qw ( fatalsToBrowser );  

$input_val = $ENV{'QUERY_STRING'};

($field_name, $command) = split (/=/, $input_val);
($file_name, $option_name) = split(/&/, $command);


$file_path= "Database/$file_name";

$directorypath = "Database/";

my $files_location;  
my @fileholder;  

$files_location = $directorypath;  

if ($file_name eq '')
{  
    print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";  
    print "File doesn't exist";  
} else {  

    open(DLFILE, "<$files_location/$file_name") || Error('open', 'file');  
    @fileholder = <DLFILE>;  
    close (DLFILE) || Error ('close', 'file');  

    print "Content-Type:application/x-download\n";  
    print "Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=$file_name\n\n";  
    print @fileholder;  
}

print "</HTML>";
exit 0;
```

Refer to this website: http://www.perlnotes.com/study0680.htm